# meaning a phrase

Tags: meaning

I'm reading a story in English (it's not my native language), two guys are spending time in a hot tub and talking and joking, and one guy answers the another

*“Mmm, deep ramming,” Mark teased.  He was pushing it with that one.

Tom splashed him.*

I check a few dictionaries and google but I don't understand what *He was pushing it with that one.* means?

Comment: I think this would be more appropriate on ELL.

Comment: I'm guessing you missed several inferences along the way, but "pushing it" is a relatively tame idiom, meaning "getting too close to the edge" (figuratively) and apt to invoke anger, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this context I would say that "He was pushing it with that one" most closely means that he is suggesting Mark is coming close to being inappropriate with his previous statement.

"Pushing it" in general means that one is approaching some sort of "line" - a moral, ethical, social, or emotional boundary that has repercussions when crossed.